# Google Cloud API Gateway User Authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-gateway

I am trying to implement user authentication via JWTs in Google Cloud API Gateway.
I have configured the security requirement object and a security definitions object in the API config as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt#configuring_apig_to_support_client_authentication)

```
securityDefinitions:
    google_id_token:
      authorizationUrl: ""
      flow: "implicit"
      type: "oauth2"
      x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
      x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
security:
   - google_id_token: []
```

And the backend service is a Cloud Run service

```
x-google-backend:
  address: https://my-apis-fskhw40mta-uk.a.run.app
```

However when I call the API with my user bearer token, I receive a 403 error and this error in the stackdriver logs

```
"jwt_authn_access_denied{Audiences_in_Jwt_are_not_allowed}"
```

The Python client code to call the API is

```
id_token = subprocess.run(['gcloud', 'auth',  'print-identity-token'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True).stdout

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
encoded_args = urlencode({'arg1': "val1"})
r = http.request(
    'GET',
    API_URL + "/run-api?" + encoded_args,
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {id_token}"}
)
```

What is the correct way to include an audience when using a **User account** (not service account)

**Update 1**
I have found one way to do it, however I'm not sure it is correct. If I add `32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com`
to the `securityDefinitions` so it looks like this

```
securityDefinitions:
    google_id_token:
      authorizationUrl: ""
      flow: "implicit"
      type: "oauth2"
      x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
      x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
      x-google-audiences: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token, 32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

It will allow unauthenticated access to Cloud Run, however I still can not call Cloud Run with authentication enabled. Cloud Run returns `403` error due to the API gateway service account not having permmissions - It has `Cloud Run Invoker`

Is there anything special I need to do to enable API Gateway to call cloud run other than granting `Cloud Run Invoker`

Comment: I tried that and got the error ` Invalid account Type for `--audiences`. Requires valid service account.` -should it work for a user account?

Comment: You need to grant the API Gateway service account the Cloud Run invoker role. You haven't any other solution, except to set the Cloud Run service public (add allUsers Cloud Run invokers on the Cloud Run service)

Comment: Yes as mentioned in the last paragraph, the API gateway service account has `"roles/run.invoker`

Comment: Can you share the roles of the api gateway service agent service account? (pattern `service-<project Number>@gcp-sa-apigateway.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) Can you also confirm that the service account used by API gateway belong to the current project? Same thing for the Cloud Run service.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere but the second issue is fixed, it was a mis configured OpenAPI spec. It is working now

Answer (score 0):

Adding 32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com is not recommended, since this is the default. Ideally the audience should be unique for every service, which is why we normally use the service's own URL for this purpose. This prevents the tokens being reused, e.g. by a malicious or insecure server, to authenticate to other services which expect a different audience.

You can specify the audience you want to use when you create your identity token. For example:  `gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences "https://service-acldswax.fx.gateway.dev"`

You can specify the same audience in `x-google-audiences` to make this work. Alternatively, the service name prefixed with "https://" will be accepted by default. This can be specified as "host" in the API specification file and would normally be something like "api.example.com".

Note that *anyone* can generate a valid identity token, which will be accepted by the gateway. The gateway is performing /authentication/, but not /authorization/. You can either do authorization in the app, or for a private API you may wish to use a different oauth2 client.

When this is set up correctly you should be able to connect to the API gateway, but you will probably want your Cloud Run service to be locked down, to prevent the gateway from being bypassed. As you mentioned, the permission required to do this is included in the "Cloud Run Invoker" role, this needs to be granted to the gateway's service account on the Cloud Run service one of its containing resources (e.g. project, folder, organization).

I would suggest running the following commands to confirm/check the settings again :

- Verify URL and API config in the gateway: gcloud api-gateway gateways describe $GATEWAY --location $REGION
- Verify gateway config service account and backend URL (in base64 encoded document.contents): gcloud api-gateway api-configs describe --api $API $API_CONFIG --view FULL
- Verify permission on Cloud Run service : gcloud run services --region $REGION get-iam-policy $SERVICE

Comment: `gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences "https://service-acldswax.fx.gateway.dev"` requires a service account, it does not work for me from a desktop. Can you confirm if this is intended to work?

Comment: You should specify the user account while running the command. For example, to print identity token for account 'foo@example.com' whose audience is 'https://service-hash-uc.a.run.app', run: ```gcloud auth print-identity-token foo@example.com --audiences="https://service-hash-uc.a.run.app```. For detailed information and steps, you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token).

Comment: I have tried this again and I still get the error `Invalid account Type for `--audiences`. Requires valid service account.`  Before running the command I am logging on with `gcloud auth login` is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Try these steps:
- Create a service account:  gcloud iam service-accounts create test-endpoint
- Generate and download the key file. Replace the PROJECT_ID with your project ID
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \--iam-account test-endpoint@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
- Activate the service account in the gcloud CLI: gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json

For detailed information and steps please refer this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/rate-limit-your-api-usage-with-cloud-endpoints-quotas-1270da55d2bf)

Comment: Yes I realise I can use a service account. This question is about User Access. It sounds like the only way to do this is to validate the token audience is `32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com` and then manage the authorisation. If there are 100,000+ customers I don't imagine the recomended approach of a project per customer is going to be very useful